# How to write a test for a Flink pipeline that uses ContinuousProcessingTimeTrigger with TumblingProcessingTimeWindows? It never outputs in test

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, scalatest

I’m trying to write a simple test but not sure why it’s not working here is my code. Not sure what I am missing. It seems like it never invoke to trigger to output in test. The pipeline is simply emits the aggregated output of string every second of every second window. What am I missing?

```scala
object CollectSink {
  val collectedResults = mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, String)]()
}

class CollectSink extends SinkFunction[(Int, String)] {
  override def invoke(value: (Int, String), context: SinkFunction.Context): Unit = {
    CollectSink.collectedResults += value
  }
}

class MyTestSuite extends BaseSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach {
  val flinkCluster = new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
    new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
      .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
      .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
      .build
  )

  override def beforeAll() = {
    flinkCluster.before()
  }

  override def beforeEach() = {
    CollectSink.collectedResults.clear()
  }

  override def afterAll() = {
    flinkCluster.after()
  }

  it should "Simple pipeline emits the expected output" in {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(2)

    val sourceDataStream = env.fromCollection(
      Seq(
        (1, "a"),
        (1, "b"),
        (2, "c"),
        (1, "d"),
        (2, "e")
      )
    )
    val collectSink = new CollectSink()

    // Sample pipeline that emits aggregated strings
    // It emits the result every second for every window of 1 second
    sourceDataStream
      .keyBy(_._1)
      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
      .trigger(ContinuousProcessingTimeTrigger.of[TimeWindow](Time.seconds(1)))
      .reduce(new ReduceFunction[(Int, String)] {
        override def reduce(value1: (Int, String), value2: (Int, String)): (Int, String) = (value1._1, value1._2 + value2._2)
      })
      .addSink(collectSink)

    env.execute()

    // Issue here is that it never collects anything somehow, size is always 0
    // It seems like the the pipeline never emits anything in this test
    CollectSink.collectedResults should have size 1
  }
}
```

**Referenced testing doc**: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs

Answer (score 1):

In order to guarantee this test produces results, it would have to run for at least one second. With only 5 events to process, that isn't happening.

Jobs with bounded sources stop once all of the input has been processed. Pending processing time timers are not called.

A couple of possible workarounds:

- Switch to using event time. Flink triggers all pending event time timers when a job with bounded sources reaches the end of its input.
- Use an unbounded source, and keep the test job running long enough so that it produces results.

Comment: Thank you for checking, hmm so I guess no easy way to test this unless making this pipeline test to wait (not sure if it's possible to force move forward the time or something), or make the source data to be big enough for the pipeline to process in the whatever time set for the pipeline (i.e. 1 second in this case)?

Comment: I've expanded my answer -- but you're right, there's no easy way to test this.